# How to handle multiple databases with single PDO instance?

Tags: php, pdo

I've a bit problem. I wrote a `PDO` wrapper that allow me to perform query on my database.

Now my application is multitenant, this means that I need different databases. The Data Source structure is structured like this:

```
(1) Main Db 

(n) Tenant DB
```

So I've a main database where I've all my companies, and n databases where I've login credentials and user company informations.

When my application start I call my db wrapper like so:

```
$this->db = new Database('host', 'name', 'user', 'pass');
```

whis will create an instance with my default configuration in my `index.php`. When my user logged in I store into a global variable the connection settings of him database.

Now the problem's that I need to use in some moment my config.php database credential, so I need to redeclare the database object again and again in each models method. This scenario is a pain.

What I can do for solve this?

Comment: if the various dbs are all on the system db server, and you can grant access to them using the SAME user/pass, then you can do `select dbname.tablename.field, otherdb.othertable.otherfield from dbname.table ...` type stuff. But if they are different dbs (e.g. mysql & postgres), and/or you need to use different credentials for each, then you will have to have two+ pdo objects.

Comment: Nice solution, but if I've different server farm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the mysql user has access to both databases, then just prepend the database name to the table name:

```
SELECT id,name FROM database_name.users_table
```

If you need to log in as a different user, then yes, you'll need to create a new PDO instance.